# editorconfig for C++ function indentation

Tags: visual-studio, editorconfig

How do I use editorconfig to control indentation of C++ function declaration in Visual Studio:
e.g.

```
int
funktion(
    int     x,
    long    y
);
```

We tried to set up in .editorconfig

`indent_style = space`

`indent_size = 4`

and get

```
int
    funktion(
        int     x,
        long    y
    );
```